# Add entity with OneToOne Relation using JPA and REST

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa

I am using Spring JPA Restful, and I don't understand how to insert an entity with a foreign key.

Activity Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name= "Activity")
public class Activity implements Serializable{

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid")
   @GenericGenerator(name="uuid", strategy = "uuid2")
   @Column(name = "uuid", nullable = false, unique = true)
   private UUID uuid;

   @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade=CascadeType.MERGE)
   @JoinColumn(name="type", nullable = false)
   private ActivityType type;

   @Column(nullable = false)
   private String label;
```

ActivityType Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name= "ActivityType")
public class ActivityType implements Serializable {

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
   private long id;

   @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
   private String code;

   @Column(nullable = false
   private String label;
```

Is it possible to insert Activity simply? With something like this JSON where ActivityType's id "1" exists:

createActivity:
    {"label":"LABEL","type":1}

With this code I have to do:

createActivity:
    {"label":"LABEL","type":{"id":1}}

which return value is:

```
{
 "uuid": "a54b27aa-8d49-41fd-8976-70c019c40e3b",
 "type": {
   "id": 1,
   "code": null,
   "label": null
 },
 "label": "LABEL",
 "details": null
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use the library *[gson](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-do-convert-java-object-to-from-json-format-gson-api/)* for parsing domain classes into JSON.

//... code for making your activity, let's say you have an Activity object myActivity

Just add the following code where you want to parse your object into JSON.

```
Gson gson = new GSON();
String json = gson.toJson(myActivity);
```